# Remove a property from an immutable JS object

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

In my react-native application, I want to remove a property of my js object which is in redux.

here is my code.

```
    case SAVE_PLAYLIST:
        const { toPlayListFrom, selectedPlaylist } = action.payload;

        let newPlaylists = // state.savedPlaylists;
            Object.keys(selectedPlaylist).length > 0
                ?  {
                    ...state.savedPlaylists,
                    [toPlayListFrom]: selectedPlaylist
                }
                : delete state.savedPlaylists[toPlayListFrom];

        return {
            ...state,
            savedPlaylists: newPlaylists
        }
```

in this line, `delete state.savedPlaylists[toPlayListFrom]` it doesn't remove the property as expected. How can I delete a property from an immutable js object in a right way?

Comment: One branch of your conditional operator returns an object, the other returns a boolean. I'm afraid I can't quite make out what you're trying to do above... What is `toPlayListFrom`? What is `selectedPlaylist`? What changes to state is the code meant to do?

Comment: Separately: Up until `delete state.savedPlaylists[toPlayListFrom]` you're doing a good job following React's [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly) on changing state (looks to me like all of this code is in a `setState` callback where `state` is the callback's first parameter). But `delete state.savedPlaylists[toPlayListFrom]` violates the rules: It modifies state directly.

Comment: A library I've personally used which is very useful in managing Redux state immutability is `immutability-helper` found here: https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper - look at the `$unset` command.

Comment: toPlayListFrom is a key  for a screen. values are (choose-workout, trainer-profile, my-profile).

selectedPlaylist is an object which includes the key and name of a playlist.

So, what is the proper way of removing a key without violating rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) statement is wrong. The command generally returns true (in a few cases it may return false.)

Also, as mentioned by T.J. Crowder, you do not want to modify the `state` variable.

First you want to create a copy of the data and then apply a delete on the copy.

```
case SAVE_PLAYLIST:
    const { toPlayListFrom, selectedPlaylist } = action.payload;

    let newPlaylists = // state.savedPlaylists;
        Object.keys(selectedPlaylist).length > 0
            ?  {
                ...state.savedPlaylists,
                [toPlayListFrom]: selectedPlaylist
            }
            : ...state.savedPlaylists;

    // only apply a delete to the copy, not the original
    //
    if (Object.keys(selectedPlaylist).length === 0) {
        delete newPlaylists.savedPlaylists[toPlayListFrom]
    }

    return {
        ...state,
        savedPlaylists: newPlaylists
    }
```

One thing to keep in mind in JavaScript is that objects use references. So if you don't first make a copy, you are changing said object (or attempting to, at least, some objects could be marked immutable (`const`, really) and thus can't be modified.)

I'm sure there are ways to optimize the above code.